# White background covering up the stars background when viewing a question

Tags: bug, design

Normally, you can see stars on the right and left of viewing a question. Like the current main page:

[image]

You can see stars.

But now, when viewing any question on the main site - or on a meta site -
 the white covers up that background:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now. (I'll defer to the devs on adding a [meta-tag:status-completed] tag though.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Given that [Paweł](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56348/pawe%c5%82) has said below that it's been fixed (and given that we can confirm it with our own eyes), I think you can probably just go ahead and add the tag. No point in leaving this report hanging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. We've already fixed that in our development environment so this should be live in next couple hours.